# Change Temporary Directory for Apache File Upload in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, servletcontextlistener

I am having a difficult time trying to change the default location of the "javax.servlet.context.tempdir" in our Tomcat's ServletContext and it just isn't working.

Here is the long and short of it.  When inspecting our ServletContext in a debugger, the attribute "javax.servlet.context.tempdir" is a read-only attribute and doesn't change when the setAttribute method is called on the ServletContext.

How can we change this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javax.servlet.context.tempdir` ServletContext attribute can be set one of two ways.

In your server.xml as an attribute of the `Host` element.

```
<Host name="localhost" workDir="directory_location">
    ...
</Host>
```

[Tomcat 8 reference on Host](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/host.html)

Or in your context.xml as an attribute of the `Context` element.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context workDir="directory_location">
    ...
</Context>
```

[Tomcat 8 reference on Context](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html)

**WARNING**

Changing this value also has the side effect of changing where tomcat stores the JSP files it compiles into classes.

Comment: Updated the answer to be more 'readable' for myself.  Thank you for pointing out where this information is.  I looked right at those two entries before, but couldn't figure out how to use them...  Your original example really helped clarify things.